# Rep type in GHC Generics

Tags: haskell, generic-programming

I am trying to build a `Default` class that automagically knows how to create default values. So I read the [relevan wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC.Generics) and my problem comes down to this: Why does this typecheck:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}

import GHC.Generics

-- From https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC.Generics (sort of)
class GSerialize f where
  gput :: f a -> [Int]
class Serialize a where
  put :: a -> [Int]
  default put :: (Generic a, GSerialize (Rep a)) => a -> [Int]
  put a = gput (from a)
```

But this doesn't

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}

import GHC.Generics

class GDefault a where
  gdef :: a
class Default a where
  def :: a
  default def :: (Generic a, GDefault (Rep a)) => a
  def = gdef . from
```

The error is:

```
• Expecting one more argument to ‘Rep a’
  Expected a type, but ‘Rep a’ has kind ‘* -> *’
• In the first argument of ‘GDefault’, namely ‘Rep a’
  In the type signature:
    def :: (Generic a, GDefault (Rep a)) => a
  In the class declaration for ‘Default’
```

Comment: The first class expects its "argument" `f` to have kind `* -> *` (since it uses it as `f a`) but your class argument `a` (of `GDefault`) expects only a type (so kind `*`), but you are still feeding it something of kind `* -> *`.

Comment: It's very unclear what this question is asking - the typechecker *told* you why the latter code doe not compile! Even if your "problem comes down to this" perhaps you should describe the actual problem.

Comment: I feel quite dumb, it's actually what Alec suggests...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler error here is helpful, but only in that annoying way where it tells you exactly what is wrong but not *why* it is wrong.

> Expected a type but "Rep a" has kind "* -> *".

So the problem here is that `Rep` (a type family) needs two arguments (call them `a` and `p`, as in `Rep a p`); it as a type-level function maps these two type arguments into the "generic" type. For example,

```
data Empty deriving Generic

instance Generic Empty where
  type Rep Empty =
    D1 ('MetaData "Empty" "Main" "package-name" 'False) V1

-- taken from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.htm
```

- `a`, e.g. `Empty`, represents the type from which we are genericizing.
- `p` is a dummy type so that we can reuse our representation types for higher-level types ([see `Generic1` in the documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html)).

So, in the above example, `Rep Empty p` would simplify to `D1 ('MetaData ...) V1 p`.

We can usually ignore `p` except when it comes to defining new typeclasses that take advantage of generics. We *want* to pattern match on on types like `D1 ('MetaData ...) V1 p` but we need some way of handling the extra parameter.

A trick then is to treat `D1 ('MetaData ...) V1` like a higher-level type (like a functor). This is our `f` in `GDefault`.

```
class GDefault f where
  gdef :: f a
```

Yes `a` will always be this stupid parameter that we will never use, but in return for line noise we get the ability to pattern match on the `f` in our instances. Here are four instances that allow for automatic generic `def` implementations for product types (`:*:` being a lifted tuple):

```
instance GDefault U1 where
  gdef = U1

instance Default a => GDefault (K1 i a) where
  gdef = K1 def

instance (GDefault a, GDefault b) => GDefault (a :*: b) where
  gdef = gdef :*: gdef

instance GDefault a => GDefault (M1 i c a) where
  gdef = M1 gdef
```

This, along with some sensible defaults for the numeric tower, will let us define datatypes like `data Foo = Foo Int Char Float deriving (Show, Generic)` and evaluate `show (def :: Foo)` to `"Foo 0 0 0.0"`.

Your code had `gdef :: a`, which is the wrong kind. We want `gdef :: f a` because the typeclass is defined on types with kind `* -> *`, hence the error message.

And to take advantage of this helper class, we do much as you did:

```
class Default a where
  def :: a

  default def :: (Generic a, GDefault (Rep a)) => a
  def = to gdef
```

`to :: Rep a x -> a` introduces a spurious `x`, which unifies with our `gdef :: f a` to produce `f ~ Rep a`, throwing away the `x` and being exactly what we intended.

[You can see this approach elaborated in the `data-default` package.](https://github.com/mauke/data-default/blob/master/data-default-class/Data/Default/Class.hs)